# Resize a video when the parent container is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

How can I resize a video when it's parent div is being resize?

```
    <div id="resizable" class="resizable" style="width:640px; height:390px; border:solid gray 1px" class="ui-widget-content">
    <object class="video" style="height: 390px; width: 640px;">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
        <embed class="video" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390">
    </object>           
</div>

$( "#resizable" ).resizable();
```

http://deadwoodfilms.com/jquery/gallery/video.html

Answer (score 2):

Just set the child elements height and width to 100%.

```
<object class="video" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery plugin out there that takes care of it called FitVids:

site: http://fitvidsjs.com/

github: https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js